# Optional map as list

Tags: terraform

I'm working on a module that wraps the [aws_dynamodb_table](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/dynamodb_table.html) resource and passes through several of the arguments. I'm having issues with some of the optional blocks e.g. `ttl`. I've discovered that, despite only being able to be specified once, `ttl` is technically a list on the resource. However, since it can only be specified once, my module defines its `ttl` variable as a map. Additionally, `ttl` is optional on the resource so I would like it to be optional on my module as well.

This is what I have so far:

I define `ttl` as an optional map like so

**variables.tf**

```
... stuff ..
variable "ttl" {
  description = "(Optional) Defines ttl"
  type = "map"
  default = {}
}
... more stuff ...
```

I then assign it to the `aws_dynamodb_table` resource

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "default" {
  ... stuff ...
  ttl = "${length(keys(var.ttl)) > 0 ? list(var.ttl) : list()}"
  ... more stuff ...
}
```

With this approach I'm getting the following error:

```
conditional operator cannot be used with list values in:

${length(keys(var.ttl)) > 0 ? list(var.ttl) : list()}
```

Is this sort of thing impossible? It seems simple enough but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried the approach of a conditional operator for this. Instead I have the default set to false. This means if the user of the module doesn't pass any values for ttl then it won't be enabled.

The variable for the module looks like this:

**variables.tf**

```
variable "ttl_configuration" {
type = "map"
 default = {
   "attribute_name" = "TimeToExist"
   "enabled" = false
 }
}
```

Then inside the module assign this variable to `ttl`, ensuring to cast it as a list:

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "default" {
  ... stuff ...
  ttl = ["${var.ttl_configuration}"]
  ... more stuff ...
}
```

Another issue to note for TTL that I have just run into is changing the `attribute_name` from one attribute to another. Terraform doesn't let you just change it, so you will need to set the current one to false, then set it to true for your new one.
This also means that with my approach above if you want to disable ttl on a table you must still pass the map in order to set the correct attribute name to false.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have used this in the past as well. My only issue with this solution is that it is not generalizable. Also, in general I'd prefer to rely on the defaults of the resource rather than specifying my own.

Comment: I was running into the same issue. I settled with this because it allowed the disabling of an existing TTL attribute.